# MYSQL to CSV with PHP with 4 blank rows at top

Tags: php, mysql, export-to-csv

There are 2 blank rows at the top of csv when script is run...Have no idea why.  This code works in another application I've made.  I'm using the same code and same database??

Does the location in directory make a difference?

```
<?php

mysql_connect("", "", "")
or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("dbname")
or die(mysql_error());
$database = "mydb"; 

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");


// Fetch Record from Database
    $output = "";
// Store Matching
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT audiolist.`Store Number`, audiolist.Address, audiolist.City, audiolist.State, audiolist.`Zip Code`, audiolist.`Install Date`
                           FROM audiolist INNER JOIN filteredlist ON audiolist.`Store Number`=filteredlist.`Store Number`"); 
    $columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($sql);       

// Get The Field Name

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
    $heading = mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
    $output .= '"'.$heading.'",';
}


$output .="\n";

// Get Records from the table

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
$output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
}
$output .="\n";
}

// Download the file

$filename =  "myfilename" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

echo $output;
exit;
```

Comment: can you paste your output here

Comment: Are the blank rows completely blank lines, or are they blank data: (`"", "", ""`...)?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, not sure how to confirm that... When cells are selected in excel, no values are displayed.

Comment: Store Number Address City State Zip Code Install Date

Comment: Not exactly sure why it matters...but apparently if there are any lines before the initial <?php tag, those lines show up as plank rows when the csv is generated.  There were two lines before mine and therefore 2 blank rows...It works now!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it matters...but apparently if there are any lines before the initial `<?php` tag, those lines show up as plank rows when the csv is generated. There were two lines before mine and therefore 2 blank rows...It works now!

Answer (score 0):

After this line of your code:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
```

Add this code:

```
 ob_clean();   // discard any data in the output buffer (if possible)
 flush();
```